# how to use Tooltip with a Dynamic point

Tags: plotting, graphics

consider this example:

```
LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt],
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[Dynamic[pt]]}, 
  PlotLabel -> Dynamic@pt], Appearance -> None]
```

I am trying to add `Tooltip` to the `pt` but without any success. the only thing I got is using `Tooltip` with the point like this: `Tooltip@Point[Dynamic[pt]]` but this will show the word `Point` also.
any solution to use Tooltip with the point `pt`

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Does this do what you desire?:

```
LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], 
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Dynamic @ Tooltip[Point[pt], pt]}, 
  PlotLabel -> Dynamic@pt], Appearance -> None]
```

Comment: Yap, than you :)